# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que al subir mi app a Playstore , esta no cambie el nombre de algunas variables de mi app?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, app

Buen día, tengo una  consulta, tengo un app que cuando la estoy corriendo desde Android Studio en mi dispositivo funciona correctamente  en su comunicación con el API, pero al momento de estar en Playstore ya la versión de producción no funciona en ciertas partes donde se envían datos al API ayer hice pruebas y descubrí que en la versión de producción la app manda las propiedades de unos objetos con otro nombre, por ejemplo el api espera una propiedad que es material y cantidad, pero la app al estar en producción manda a y b como propiedades, alguna idea de por que pasa esto?

Comment: ¿Cual es la API con la que trabajas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es porque por default la versión release tiene activada la minificación. Esto acorta los nombres de todas las clases y sus miembros, a menos que le indiques lo contrario. Hay dos opciones para hacerlo. La mas simple es agregar la anotación `@Keep` a la clase que quieres que mantenga sus nombres.

```
@Keep
class ExampleClass{}
```

Si necesitas mas control debes crear tus reglas en el archivo "proguard-rules.pro". Algunos ejemplos:

- `-keep class com.example.ExampleClass` esta es lo mismo que la anotación `@Keep`
- `-keep class * implements com.example.ExampleInterface` mantiene todas las clases que implementen la interface
- `-keep class * extends com.example.ExampleClass` mantiene todas las subclases de la clase indicada
- `-keep class com.example.**` mantiene todas las clases que existan dentro de ese package

Alternativamente puedes usar todas estas reglas reemplazando la palabra `keep` por `keepclassmembers`. Esto acorta el nombre de la clase pero el mantiene el de sus miembros. Ejemplo `-keepclassmembers class com.example.ExampleClass`

Comment: Cheque la documentación antes de leer tu respuesta y si era por eso  , gracias